# How to dynamically create hubsections in windows universal apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have an `ObservableCollection` that contains a number of objects that depends on the users interaction with the app.

I want to represent every object as a `HubSection`, and since I don't know the number of objects, the HubSections must be generated dynamically from the code behind of the View.

In the code behind of the view (xaml.cs file), I made a loop that goes through the collection, and starts creating a HubSection in every iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
        {
            tempHubSection = new HubSection();
            tempHubSection.Header = vm.MyCollection[i].Name;
            DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();
            ???
            mainHub.Sections.Add(tempHubSection);
        }
```

But I got a little confused about how to create a DataTemplate and insert a Grid inside it, such as this:

```
<HubSection Width="700" Header="object-1">
      <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                        ...
                </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `DataTemplate` code to the resources section of `app.xaml` file, give the name, for example `myTemplate`.

```
  <DataTemplate  x:Key="myTemplate">
            <Grid>
                    ...
            </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
```

and then you'll be able to assign it in code:

```
mainHub.Template = (ControlTemplate)App.Current.Resources["myTemplate"];
```